# Unable to use imagecopyresized in amazon ec2 linux server

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, php-gd

- I am trying to upload and re-size images on amazon linux server with the below code.
- It works fine in my local system. But not on server. I get Server error 500.
- Error occurs only on this line `if(!imagecopyresized($new_image, $old_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height)){return false;}`
- I've gone through a plenty of solution nothing fits, is there any option or alternative fix this?

  ```
  function makeThumbnails($updir, $img, $id, $name, $extension, $MaxWe = 150, $MaxHe = 150) {
      ini_set ( "memory_limit", "48M");
      $arr_image_details = getimagesize($img);

      $width = $arr_image_details[0];
      $height = $arr_image_details[1];
      $percent = 100;
      if ($width > $MaxWe)
          $percent = floor(($MaxWe * 100) / $width);

      if (floor(($height * $percent) / 100) > $MaxHe)
          $percent = (($MaxHe * 100) / $height);

      if ($width > $height) {
          $newWidth = $MaxWe;
          $newHeight = round(($height * $percent) / 100);
      } else {
          $newWidth = round(($width * $percent) / 100);
          $newHeight = $MaxHe;
      }

      if ($arr_image_details[2] == 1) {
          $imgt = "ImageGIF";
          $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromGIF";
      }
      if ($arr_image_details[2] == 2) {
          $imgt = "ImageJPEG";
          $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromJPEG";
      }
      if ($arr_image_details[2] == 3) {
          $imgt = "ImagePNG";
          $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromPNG";
      }
      if ($imgt) {
          $old_image = $imgcreatefrom($img);
          $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);

          if ($arr_image_details[2] == 3) {
              imagealphablending($new_image, false);
              imagesavealpha($new_image, true);
          }
          if(!imagecopyresized($new_image, $old_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height)){
              return false;
          }
          $imgt($new_image, $updir . "" . $name);
          return true;
    }
  ```

  }

Comment: Did you look in the log's what they are saying?

Comment: Yes, "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function ImageCreateFromJPEG()". But GD is there already

Comment: think its not compiled with libjpeg. Postet an answer how to install PHP with libjpeg. Thats why all other function works but not the ImageCreateFromJpeg Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your failure. My Guess it that it's not compiled with libjpeg. For ImageCreateFromJPEG you need gd and libjpeb. Make sure to run configure with --with-jpeg-dir. You may have to search for it. I used the command find / -name libjpeg* and got /usr/lib for CentOS5.

Complete compilation of PHP is as follows:

```
wget http://us1.php.net/distributions/php-5.5.10.tar.gz -O php.tar.gz
tar -xvf php.tar.gz
cd php-5.5.10
yum -y install libxml2-devel libmcrypt-devel libpng-devel
./configure --with-config-file-path=/etc --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d  --with-apxs2 --with-mysql --with-mysqli --with-zlib --with-curl --with-libdir=lib --with-openssl --with-pdo-mysql --with-mcrypt  --with-pcre-regex --enable-zip --with-gd --enable-mbstring --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib
make clean
make
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the GD library for php

```
sudo yum install php55-gd
```